# Run-time of a function to find the (n / 2^k)th element of a list of size n?

Tags: big-o, analysis

I can imagine only two cases: as 2^k approaches n, (say, if 2^k == n), then the number of steps required is n / n, or 1, so it has a run-time of O(1).

However, if 2^k is small, (say, if 2^k == 1), then n steps are required, so it has a run-time of O(n).

In essence, if 2^k can be written in terms of n, then the number of steps required is an integer, so it has a run-time of O(1). If 2^k cannot be written in terms of n, it has a run-time of O(n).

Both of these cases are worst-case; for any unknown and possibly large n, these run-times still hold. Is there any situation in which 2^k can't be qualified as much smaller than n *or* close to n?

Imagine you were to write a (possibly very long) table containing the run-times for the function for values of k such that (n / 2^k) >= 1. As k starts at 0 and increases, the run-times are O(1), but as k starts at a large value and decreases, the run-times are O(n). Is there a theoretical point at which the run-time switches from O(1) to O(n)?

Or am I simply not grasping the "main idea" of Big-O analysis?

EDIT: A linear search is assumed

Comment: Are you using binary search?

Comment: @TobiAlafin A linear search is assumed (I just made an edit)

Comment: Ok. This makes sense to me now.

Comment: "then the number of steps required is an integer, so it has a run-time of O(1)." This is wrong. (n/2^k) being an integer, e.g the fourth element, gives you a run time of the integer you got. This integer is less than n, so it is O(n).

Comment: I'm adding an answer right now.

Comment: try [cs.se] for lots of Big-O theory. this seems to be phrased awkwardly but it looks like youre essentially asking about accessing an element of a sorted list. so the problem is basically about run times of sorting algorithms which is a heavily studied area of CS.

Comment: @vzn, Nooooh. If all the Big-Oh, analysis and complexity questions go to CS how will I gain rep here on SO? I was overjoyed when I saw these tags today realising that I could finally start netting rep on this site. (I have fr more downvotes than upvotes in general).

Comment: @jelvin, please consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You’re missing a main idea of big-O analysis.  There’s always an assumption (usually unstated) that you’re looking at a limit as something goes to infinity.  Usually, there’s only one variable, so it’s clear from context that that’s the variable going to infinity.  (For example, `n^2+23n∈O(n^2)` (as `n` goes to infinity).)

In your case, you have two variables, `n` and `k`.  So in order to talk about big-O, you need to quantify what is going to infinity (it looks to be `n`), and what the other variable is doing in the meantime.  This does lead to your two possibilities: if `k` is constant as `n` goes to infinity, then the answer is `O(n)`; but if `k` is such that `n/2^k` is constant (i.e., `k=lg(n)-C`), then the answer is `O(1)`.  But there are other possibilities: if `n/2^k=√n` (i.e., `k=lg(n)/2`), then the answer is `O(√n)`.

So depending on how `k` grows with `n`, the answer is anything between `O(1)` and `O(n)`.

Comment: Can't you just assume `k` has any value between `0 and lg(n)`. The question implies as such. In that case, worst case is 'k' has a value of '0', and we end up with `f(n) = O(n)`

Comment: If `k` can range over all possible values, then yes, we take the worst case.  But if `k` is fixed in terms of `n`, then we have to analyze what's happening for that `k`.

Comment: He didn't give any information about `k`, so I just used range of possible values.

Answer (score 1):

> However, if 2^k is small, (say, if 2^k == 1), then n steps are required, so it has a run-time of O(n). (1)
>
> In essence, if 2^k can be written in terms of n, then the number of steps required is an integer, so it has a run-time of O(1). If 2^k cannot be written in terms of n, it has a run-time of O(n).(2)

(1)'s conclusion is correct, but (2) is wrong.

First of all, you have 2 variables. `n` and `k`. `k:  1 <= 2^k <= n`

If `n = 128`, and `k = 4` `128/2^4 = 4`

Number of steps is `4` not `1`.

In general, if `n` is a power of `2` say `2^x`, then number of steps `f(n) =` 2^x/2^k = 2^(x-k)`

now `n = 2^x`, Using basic logarithms, `x = lg(n)` {Where `lg(y)` is the log to base 2 of y'

`f(n) = 2^{lg(n)-k}`      (1)

The run time is `2^{lg(n)-k}` if n is not divisible by `2^k`, then you are attempting to access a number at a floating point index which does not exist.

Assuming you want me to round the index to the nearest integer. Indexes are only integers after all.

Now 1 gives you the simple run time formula. But the worst case, is when `k = 0`. SInce Big-Oh uses worst case, we go with that.

`f(n) = O(2^{lg(n)-0})`
`f(n) = O(2^{lg(n)}`

This is the Anti-log of `lg(n)` which again from basic logarithm knowledge gives us `n`.

Therefore `f(n) = O(n)`

Q.E.D